# Can I retrieve the user password, or a symbolic URL, using Siebel eScript?

Tags: siebel

We have a Siebel 7.8 application that integrates with another webapp.

We implemented it by [creating a symbolic URL and embedding it](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/siebel/ISA/OBE_SymbolicURL/OBE_symbolicURL.htm) in a Siebel applet within one of our views. But the external webapp has transition animations between pages, which causes some problems in Siebel (specifically, in our CTI toolbar).

So, we removed the applet from our view, and open it as a popup instead. To make it work as a popup we also had to change the symbolic URL definition: instead of "IFrame", now it has "Form redirect" *SSO disposition*. It works... but it's also giving us some trouble (when the popup is opened, all the applets based on the same BC start acting weird).

Since we are no longer showing the webapp embeded in Siebel, we don't really need the symbolic URL, we could just do `window.open("http://example.com");`. But we are passing some parameters in the URL, and one of them is the current user's password. The login name, I can get with `TheApplication().LoginName()`. **Is there any way to retrieve the password too?**

From my research so far, the answer is "no". Which leads to the next question: **is there any way in which I could retrieve the full symbolic URL**, from a server or browser script? I can't find anything related in the [object interfaces reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/OIRef/OIRefInterfaceRef37.html#wp1008741), but perhaps there is an undocumented method for that?

Or maybe there is another way to implement this requeriment? It's just opening a popup in Siebel, but the URL must contain the user's password, amongst other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was easier than expected. *There is* a way to retrieve the current user's password. [Undocumented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/PortalFrame/PortalFrameTxNBS.html) as usual in Siebel, but it works anyway:

```js
function getCurrentUserPassword() {
    var service = TheApplication().GetService("Web Engine HTTP TXN");
    var psIn = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
    var psOut = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();

    service.InvokeMethod("GetAllRequestParameters", psIn, psOut);
    return psOut.GetProperty("SWEPassword");
}
```

Comment: I was about to type this answer and I see you already figured it out :)